# MS Server 2003 What fills \Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows NT\NTBackup\

Tags: windows-server-2003

What creates them? There is over 1GB of files and I need to free up some space on the C drive ASAP.. Can I change the location they are saved to another drive? Can I delete them?

They are all VO1 files - I see they are used for backup restoration so I am going to del all the ones I have so not still have the backups they correspond to anyway. Do I need them anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are "catalog" files created by ntbackup. They carry redundant information about your backup run's contents. You can delete this data and re-generate it as needed by running "catalog file" from ntbackup itself.

The catalog files come handy if your backups are going to tape and you want to be able to browse your backups without having the media inserted and re-wound for each browsed backup set. They are just a local copy of your backups' tables of contents.